# Unsure how to fix "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside module" error in nodejs/expressjs even using "type": "module"

Tags: node.js, express

I'm struggling to fix this error I'm getting here because of an `aws-sdk` import I'm making in a file called `s3.js` that's in the root directory of my backend folder on the same level as my `server.js` file:

[image]

```
import aws from 'aws-sdk'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1177:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1221:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1311:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:962:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1139:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:121:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/simerusmahesh/Code/queens_cpp/Queens-Community-Partnership-Project/backend/server.js:8:12)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1257:14)

Node.js v20.3.1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting..
```

When I do add `"type": "module"` in my `package.json` file, now I'm getting this error for all my `require` statements:

```
require('dotenv').config()
^

ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/Users/simerusmahesh/Code/queens_cpp/Queens-Community-Partnership-Project/backend/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
    at file:///Users/simerusmahesh/Code/queens_cpp/Queens-Community-Partnership-Project/backend/server.js:1:1
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:192:25)
    at async DefaultModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:246:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:40:7)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:66:12)

Node.js v20.3.1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Here is my s3.js and server.js code:

**s3.js**

```
import aws from 'aws-sdk'

const region = process.env.AWS_REGION
const bucketName = process.env.AWS_NAME
const accessKeyId = process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
const secretAccessKey = process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_ID

const s3 = new aws.S3({
    region, 
    accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey,
    signatureVersion: 'v4'
})

export async function generateUploadURL() {
    const imageName = "random name"

    const params = ({
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: imageName,
        Expires: 60
    })

    const uploadURL = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise('putObject', params)
    return uploadURL
}
```

**server.js**

```
require('dotenv').config()

const express =  require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const projectRoutes = require('./routes/projects')

// import aws s3 server code
const s3 = require("./s3.js")


const bodyParser = require("body-parser")

// express app
const app = express()


// middleware
app.use(express.json())


app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.path, req.method)
    next()
})

// image upload
app.get('/api/upload', (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        t: "sdfsd"
    })
    
})

// routes
app.use('/api/projects', projectRoutes)

// connect to db
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)
    .then(() => {
        // listening to requests once connected to DB
        app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
            console.log('Connected to DB, listening on port 4000')
        })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
```

I'm not sure how to fix the Syntax error without replacing all my require statements, if I do replace them all will this fix it? Additionally, what's the difference between using require and import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the "type": "module" line from your package.json file.  
Rename the file s3.js to have the .cjs extension, e.g., s3.cjs. 
Change the import statement import aws from 'aws-sdk' to const aws = require('aws-sdk')

Comment: Now it's saying `SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'` for the word `export` in my `s3.cjs` file when I'm creating the async function called `generateUploadURL()`, do you know how to fix this?

Comment: you are using commonjs syntax now. look into it. how to do export in commonjs. you need to do module.export instead of export.